# Multiple select count with multiple condition in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, case

I have 2 table customer and appointment:

Customer as:

| id | fullname | created_day | province_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 2023-12-25 | 1 |
| 2 | Jerry | 2023-11-22 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |  |

Appointment as:

| id | customer_id | appointment_date | accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-12-25 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-11-22 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-11-12 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |

I need to combine 3 query when select, help me:

**Query 1**:

```
Select count(*) as totalLead
from customer
where created_day between '2023-12-01' and '2023-12-31'
group by province_id;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT count(App.id) AS `totalAppointment`, `province_id` 
FROM `customer` 
LEFT JOIN (select id, customer_id from appointment where appointment_date between '2023-12-01' and '2023-12-31' group by customer_id) as App ON App.customer_id = customer.id 
WHERE customer.province_id is not null
GROUP BY `province_id`
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT count(App.id) AS `totalAppointmentAccepted`, `province_id` 
FROM `customer` 
LEFT JOIN (select id, customer_id from appointment where accepted = 1 and appointment_date between '2023-12-01' and '2023-12-31' group by customer_id) as App ON App.customer_id = customer.id 
WHERE customer.province_id is not null
GROUP BY `province_id`
```

Result:

| province_id | totalAppointment | totalAppointmentAccepted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 15 | 6 |

Comment: `COUNT(column) WHERE condition` == `SUM(CASE WHEN condition THEN column END)`. This allows to count a bunch of different conditions in one statement.

Comment: PS. Your subqueries are incorrect and non-deterministic. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Fix errors.

Comment: Thank, i delete ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in mode mysql.